# send "hi" to all contacts in telegram using telethon

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telethon

I use telethon in python3.7.
I want to get a list for all me contacts and send "hi" to them.

code:

```
async def main():

try:
    async with TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash) as client:
        result = await client(functions.contacts.GetContactsRequest(
        hash=0
        ))
        await print(result.stringify())
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

for u in result.users:
    await client.send_message(InputPeerUser(u.id, u.access_hash), "hi")

with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

But I got the error:     raise ConnectionError('Cannot send requests while disconnected')
ConnectionError: Cannot send requests while disconnected

Answer (score 0):

`with client` calls `start()` on the client when you enter the `with` block, and `disconnect` when you exit it. `client.send_message` is outside the `with` block, so it fails. This is the right way to do it:

```py
import asyncio

async def main():
    async with TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash) as client:
        result = await client(functions.contacts.GetContactsRequest(hash=0))
        for u in result.users:
            await client.send_message(u, "hi")

asyncio.run(main())
```

If you needed to define the client outside, do this instead:

```py
client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)

async def main():
    # code using client...

with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

(or `async with client` inside `main()`).

Comment: ran ur first one, it shows error:    result = await future
telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.PeerFloodError: Too many requests (caused by SendMessageRequest)

Comment: That's because you've tried messaging too many different accounts too fast. You shouldn't be able to message them with official clients either.